# In a customized burn application how can we not install anything if license does not match

Tags: wix

I have created a sample custom burn application (BA) using Wix. When the BA runs we want to not install anything and exit if a secret code is not entered correctly. I copied over the standard theme and changed the Install page as shown below to add an editbox with Name=SecretCode, and added a variable to the Bundle to receive SecretCode. When the BA runs the user enters the secret code and the code shows up in the log and InstallCondition evaluates to false, but the msi is still installed. In the ExePackage documentation the InstallCondition states:

"The package will only be installed if the condition evaluates to true. If the condition evaluates to false and the bundle is being installed, repaired, or modified, the package will be uninstalled."

In my case the BA is installing, and even though the secret code does not match the msi is still installed. I cannot pass in command line args, and would like to stay away from a custom managed application. This is a simplified example to demonstrate our problem.

Is there a way to get this working or something I am doing wrong?

**Log**

[1FE4:12AC][2016-04-08T15:07:01]i000: Setting string variable 'SecretCode' to value 'boo'
[1FE4:230C][2016-04-08T15:07:01]i052: Condition 'SecretCode=foo' evaluates to false.
[1FE4:230C][2016-04-08T15:07:01]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Netfx46Full
[1FE4:230C][2016-04-08T15:07:01]i052: Condition 'SecretCode=foo' evaluates to false.
[1FE4:230C][2016-04-08T15:07:01]i201: Planned package: MySetup, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None

**Install Page**

```
    <Page Name="Install">

    <!--
    <Richedit Name="EulaRichedit" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="-70" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HexStyle="0x800000" />
    <Checkbox Name="EulaAcceptCheckbox" X="-11" Y="-41" Width="260" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallAcceptCheckbox)</Checkbox>
    -->

    <Text Name="SomeText" X="60" Y="50" Width="-11" Height="-70" TabStop="no" FontId="0" >
    <![CDATA[
    Please enter the secret code in the following field.
    ]]>
    </Text>

    <Editbox Name="SecretCode" X="85" Y="150" Width="-91" Height="21" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" FileSystemAutoComplete="no"  />

    <Button Name="OptionsButton" X="-171" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallOptionsButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="InstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="WelcomeCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallCloseButton)</Button>
</Page>
```

**Bundle.wxs**

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
  xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension" >

<Bundle Name="My Bootstrapper" Version="8.0.0.682" Manufacturer="FooBar" UpgradeCode="33AAE528-A1F0-45DD-AAF5-A83B4B749F10">

<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaThemeXml" Value="Themes\ExtractionTheme.xml" />
<Variable Name="SecretCode" bal:Overridable="yes"/>

<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense" >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication SuppressOptionsUI="yes" LicenseUrl=""  LogoFile="graphics\logo.png" LogoSideFile="graphics\logoSide.png"  />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>

      <MsiPackage 
    Id="MySetup" 
    Cache="no" Compressed="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" 
    InstallCondition="SecretCode=foo" 
    SourceFile="SetupFiles\MyInstaller.msi" />



    </Chain>

  </Bundle>

</Wix>
```

Comment: The Burn log includes details about the plan. Look for lines starting with "Planned package" for those details.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I added the setting of the variable and the plan details